# проверка label (tkinter) на пустое значение

Tags: python, tkinter, label

```
res = StringVar()
result = Label(textvariable=res, bd=4, bg='#67ACB6', font='arial 15')
result.place(height=65, width=630, y=400, x=150)
```

Как проверить является ли label пустой строкой?

Я пытался использовать сравнение:

```
res == ''
```

но в этой переменной хранится 'PY_VAR3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы хотите проверить, есть ли в метке `Label` какой-либо текст, необходимо обратиться к параметру `"text"`:

```
result = Label(textvariable=res, bd=4, bg='#67ACB6', font='arial 15')
if result["text"] == "":
    ...
```

Если хотите проверить значение переменной типа `StringVar`, тогда нужно воспользоваться методом `get()`:

```
res = StringVar()
if res.get() == "":
    ...
```